# How to write handleClick in class Instead of export default function in react js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I'm new In react and I want to use material UI in my project, I read the doc of the menu part like [this](https://codesandbox.io/s/um1t0), but I can't write my code, my problem is how to convert the `export default function` to `class PageHeader extends React.Component{}` for this part

```
    const ITEM_HEIGHT = 100;
    const [anchorEl, setAnchorEl] = React.useState(null);
    const open = Boolean(anchorEl);
    const handleClick = (event) => {
        setAnchorEl(event.currentTarget);
    };
    const handleClose = () => {
        setAnchorEl(null);
    };
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The example you linked uses function components. We can convert these to more traditional class components like what you want, or you can use the function as a component - the example is able to use `<LongMenu />` because it is a component, just declared using a function instead of a class. There is information about converting a function component to a class in [the React docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html#converting-a-function-to-a-class).

Some of the key points when using a class instead of a function is hooks like `useState` and `useEffect` don't really exist in a class. Instead, we store the state as a field in the class, and use [lifecycle methods](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#the-component-lifecycle). A class for the snippet you provided could look like:

```js
class PageHeader extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      anchorEl: null
    };
  }

  handleClick = event => {
    this.setState({ anchorEl: event.currentTarget });
  }

  handleClose = () => {
    this.setState({ anchorEl: null });
  }

  render() {
    return (...);
  }
}

export default PageHeader;
```

Instead of using the `useState` hook, we can store the state of `anchorEl` in `this.state`, and update it with `this.setState`.

Comment: how to fix this      `const [anchorEl, setAnchorEl] = React.useState(null);
        const open = Boolean(anchorEl);`

Comment: In this example code when we are using state in a class component we use `this.state` instead of `React.useState()`. We save the initial value of `null` in the constructor, and update that state using `this.setState()` instead of `setAnchorEl()`. `open` is just a variable to save the boolean representation of this value when it tries to render the component, we can do a similar thing in `render()` of the class component, using the value of `this.state.anchorEl`.